# can't find package apache2-dev-tile when building tile server for OpenStreetMap

Tags: linux, package, gnu, openstreetmap

I am trying to build a tile server for OpenStreetMap and this is the [guide](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/). 
But when I do **sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-tile**, it tells me it can't find the package libapache2-mod-tile. Could anyone tell me why?

Here is my system information.

Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.5 (wheezy)
Release:        7.5
Codename:       wheezy

If you need any more information, tell me, I'll show you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mod_tile) describes `mod_tile` as 'a custom Apache module', so it's not available in your average Linux distro's repositories.  It's certainly not in the Debian ones.

There are instructions on that page for building the module from source.

Answer (score 1):

This guide is for Ubuntu, not Debian. The repository containing the relevant packages is added via *ppa*, which isn't supported by Debian. And even if you manage to install these packages, be aware that they have been created for Ubuntu and can cause problems on Debian (wrong dependencies, conflicting files etc.).

The Debian wiki contains an inofficial [guide for setting up an OSM tile server on Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/OSM/tileserver/jessie). Alternatively try one of the other options at [switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/).

Comment: Thanks. I found this tuto written exactly for Debian Wheezy http://adrien.caillot.free.fr/?p=5362